Undocumented Excel Command Line Arg
Excel saves a copy of a workbook in AppData every time I close the workbook and select the "Do Not Save" option. I found the setting to disable this behavior, but I am curious about the files left behind.
My workbook is a password protected .xlsx file that I open in Excel on one computer and LibreOffice on another.
In AppData, I found two files:

*MyFileName*((Unsaved-*bignumber*)).xlsb - a binary version of my workbook
*MyFileName*.xlsx - a shortcut to the original .xlsx file

The shortcut target is:
*OriginalPath*\*MyFileName*.xlsx 50
Question: What is the argument 50 for?  This list of switches does not include a numeric arg  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Excel

I believe the 50 is not a switch. Rather it should be file name. The sequence should be something like: <program -switches filename[s]. Some experimenting reveals that the subsequent file names will inherit the pathname and file suffix of the initial file.

Ron, thanks for considering the question!  That makes sense.  If true, though, it leads to other questions, such as why does Excel think there's a file called 50.xlsx at my original path and what does it intend to do with it in the context of restoring an "unsaved" version of MyFileName the next time I open it?  I still kinda suspect Excel is doing something undocumented and hacky here.  Wouldn't be the first time! :D

Did you check system and hidden files at that location to see if that exists? And what it contains?
